# Proving that for all event $A,B\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,$ $P(A\cap B)+P(A\cap \bar B)=P(A)$

Tags: probability

Prove that for all event $A,B$

$P(A\cap B)+P(A\cap \bar  B)=P(A)$

**My attempt:**

Formula: $\color{blue}{P(A\cap B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cup B)}$

$=\overbrace {P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cup B)}^{=P(A\cap B)}+\overbrace {P(A)+P(\bar B)-P(A\cup \bar B}^{=P(A\cap \bar B)})$

$=2P(A)+\underbrace{P(B)+P(\bar B)}_{=1}-P(A\cup B)-P(A\cup \bar B)$

$=1+2P(A)-P(A\cup B)-P(A\cup \bar B)$

Comment: Your formula implies that $P(C\cup D)=P(C)+P(D)$ for disjoint sets $C$ and $D$. Use that.

Comment: $=1+2P(A)-P(A\cup B)-P(A\cup \bar B)$                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       $=1+2P(A)-P(A)-P(B)-P(A)-P( \bar B)$                                                                                                                                                                                                   $=0$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$A\cap B$ and $A \cap \bar{B}$ are disjoint and their union is precisely $A$.
$$(A\cap B) \cap (A \cap \bar{B}) = A \cap A \cap (B \cap \bar{B}) = A \cap A \cap \varnothing = \varnothing$$
$$(A \cap B) \cup (A \cap \bar{B}) = A \cap (B \cup \bar{B}) = A \cap \Omega = A$$

Answer (score 0):

If you draw Venn Diagrams, you will see [image]

Hence you can conclude that $$P(A\cap\bar B)=P(A)-P(A\cap B)=P(A-B)$$

And the rest follows.